# iOS - UILabel with different format

Tags: ios, label, alignment

is it possible to have an UILabel like this?

**TITLE_LABEL** *long description label \n
that end in like this*

I hope you understand what i mean. Sorry, but i'm italian :)
TITLE_LABEL is one label with certain format.
long description label is an UILabel that start at the end of TITLE_LABEL, its size will be TITLE_LABEL.frame.size.width + some pixels and when spaces in label finish, text continue under TITLE_LABEL with left alignment. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is one only : use a web view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSString extension method, [sizeWithFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to know the exact width that TITLE_LABEL will take. Then you can place the next UILabel after the TITLE_LABEL.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not only one solution. You can read about CoreText Framework. 
Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It is not that easy to use like UIWebView but the performance is way better.

Here are few [examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW1)